# Azure App service not working with custom routing in React-Redux web app - need wildcard virtual directories?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, routes, azure-web-app-service

I have custom routes like follows:

```
// @flow

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

import { Route } from 'components/Routes';
import Story from 'pages/Story';
import Page404 from 'pages/404';

class Routes extends PureComponent<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Story {...props} />} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/chapter/:id"
          render={props => <Story {...props} />}
        />
        <Route path="/404" render={props => <Page404 {...props} />} />
        <Redirect to="/404" /* Must be the last one */ />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Routes);
```

This works fine in localhost, if I visit localhost:3000/chapter/3 the web app redirects successfully, unfortunately in live builds running on azure app services if I visit: mysite.azurewebsites.net/chapter/3 I'm given an error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I'm running a Windows based App Service plan. I'm sure there's some option to set up redirecting, i.e. /chapter/* -> /www_siteroot/ but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

I fixed the issue by going to the app service settings and adding /chapter/1, /chapter/2, etc, etc under 'Virtual applications and directories' and directing them to site\wwwroot.

I'd prefer to have a wildcard option like /chapter/* but it doesn't seem to work and I get an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're on Windows based App Service Plan, your Azure webapp is running under IIS with URL Rewriting module enabled. As such, you can create a simple `URL Rewrite` rule that directs all requests coming from `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/chapter/*` to your site root in which case the client will receive your `React/Redux` application, and your `React` application would take care of all subsequent logic and rendering of content etc..

Here are the steps to create this `URL Rewrite` rule:

1. In Azure Portal, create [FTP deployment credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp).
2. Locally on your computer, create a `Web.config` file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Chapter-Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="chapter/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

3. Open up FTP client (Filezilla is a good one) and login to your site and upload the `Web.config` file.
4. Test by visiting: `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/chapter/*`

Here's more info on [IIS URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

Comment: @Mike I am running the app service on Linux server on Azure. I tried this solution but it does not work.

Answer (score 14):

If you have your repo connected to the Azure Web App, then you can place this `web.config` file in the `/public` folder of a create-react-app project.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>

        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true"/>

        <!-- <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="120.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
        </staticContent> -->
        <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
                <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
                <add extension=".svg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
                <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
            </profiles>
        </caching>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: All I want to say is Thank you for this. Been fighting this issue for a week and you resolved it for me in 1 min.

Comment: @ericswyang  I am running the app service on a Linux server on Azure. I tried this solution but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to those who are running App Service with **Linux** is to create configuration file `.htaccess` instead of web.config. Create this file to root of your public folder with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^[^\.]+$" "index.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same with a Azure Static Web App using a Create React App that deploys from GitHub. None of the above seemed to work for me, but adding a `staticwebapp.config.json` in my project's root with the following got URL rewriting working properly again:

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": ["*.{svg,png,jpg,gif}","*.{css,scss}","*.js"]
  }
}
```

See the [documentation about Fallback Routes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes).

Comment: The difference here is _Azure Static Web App_ versus _Azure App Service Web App_. They are two distinct offerings under Azure