# React JS App Routing Issue Only After Deploying to Azure Web App

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-router, azure-web-app-service

I have a React JS app, with React Router.During development, npm start, I get no issues. I visit the following location as usual.

```
http://localhost:3000
```

and due to the routing code, it becomes

```
http://localhost:3000/index
```

and the app loads just fine. At this point,

- I hit reload, the app continues to run fine.
- I manual link or load 'http://localhost:3000/index', the app runs fine.

Then, later, I do an npm build, go inside this build folder, and do an npm start, again, the same thing. the app runs just fine. I reload, it runs fine. Nothing to complain so far.

*Problem Portion.*

I then decided to deploy the app to an azure web app. The app runs fine. I go to this site.

```
https://randomstuffreactjsappsept24.azurewebsites.net
```

and due, to routing code, it becomes

```
https://randomstuffreactjsappsept24.azurewebsites.net/index
```

And, the website loads.

At this point, if I hit reload (problem!!), it will try to reload,

```
https://randomstuffreactjsappsept24.azurewebsites.net/index
```

I get the following error.

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Now, at this point, if I remove the '/index' and load the original url,

```
https://randomstuffreactjsappsept24.azurewebsites.net
```

The site loads just fine, no problem. Note, you can see it for yourself. this is a live site. (but of course, due to routing code, it becomes)

```
https://randomstuffreactjsappsept24.azurewebsites.net/index
```

Now, as long as I dont reload the website, the website continues to run. Why is this happening?

Here is the code for the main index.js page from the project.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/index" render={(props) => <Index {...props} />} />
      <Redirect to="/index" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The full app is available here - https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/RandomStuffReactJSApp

**Update 2**

I decided to try another react app, created by another source entirely. Once again, same issue, and I have a live site to show.

- I visit, https://auth0tokenreactjsappprivatesept25.azurewebsites.net/external-api, from within the web app, it works fine. If i were to reload at this point, it will say "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
- I visit, http://localhost:3000/external-api, from within the app, it works fine. AND, If I were to reload, it loads just fine.

So, its definitely "only" happening after deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1612
You would have to place the:
Simply place the following file called web.config under your wwwroot folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Add the `web.config` file to the Azure directory.

Comment: Hi. but, I am not using react-boilerplate. not sure this applies to me.

Comment: i think you might be right about this. I have seen similar solutions in other places. i will update after further investigation.

Comment: i linked the solution you provided with the discussion here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753669/azure-app-service-not-working-with-custom-routing-in-react-redux-web-app-need/50767709, and it worked. excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I came accross this issue yesterday after using a custom build in my azure web app deployment (skipped it using `skip_app_build = false` and build it in a previous job).

My error was that my `staticwebapp.config.json` file was not located in the public folder -> it was not deployed correctly. after inserting any route a 404 was thrown by azure.

Just move the `staticwebapp.config.json` into the public folder and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Our Azure App Servive was running PHP and Apache, so we used a `.htaccess` file like this one suggested in the deployment docs of Create React App. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

```sh
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Add the `.htaccess` to the public folder and this stops your refresh issue these types of Aapp Services.