# Why does my React app say 404 not found when I refresh a page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, uinavigationbar, page-refresh

I have a React app deployed with Nginx in a AWS EC2 instance and it runs well when I use navigation bar to open a page.

But when I refresh a page, it says 404 not found even though it works correctly with navigation.

[image]

Both front-end(React) and back-end(Node) services are running in the server.

And my Nginx configuration is below.

[image]

Comment: You need a catch all route in the back end. Like `app.get('*', function(req, res) { // copy paste the root path code here });`. Front end navigation with something like `react-router` and hitting the backend routes directly (like with a page refresh or manually entering address in the address bar and hitting enter) aren't the same thing.

Comment: do you have web.config?

Comment: something similar happened to me - on Azure Web App. Look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051157/react-js-app-routing-issue-only-after-deploying-to-azure-web-app . it is probably an app configuration issue

Comment: @EranAmarante, I am not using IIS, so it has no web.config.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is my `index.js` route in Node back-end.
And imported it to `app.js` in the root folder.

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
```

And Jade is installed, but never used.
Please let me know any updates for this issue.