# Unable to access specific rest apis due to azure error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

My application using spring rest and deployed in Azure server. Created rest apis using spring rest.

Am able to access all rest urls, except in one scenario.

for eg:  `http://mydomain123.com/api/abc` , `http://mydomain123.com/api/xyz/abc`

Am able to access above urls

`http://mydomain123.com/api/bin` , `http://mydomain123.com/api/xyz/bin` , `http://mydomain123.com/api/bin/dfdff`

But above urls having bin word with which am getting below error:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I am trying as below,but not working at all:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please someone help me out to fix above issue (I should be able to access rest apis even having word "bin" in it)

Comment: any solution for above issue?

Comment: anyone reply please

Comment: no one knows above ?

Comment: Do you see any logs on the `springrest` app? If yes, can you post them? It's hard to guess without logs

Comment: @harshavmb  no error logs, all am seeing response as "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."  which is coming from Azure end whenever I ran any rest api having word "bin" in it. how do I fix this issue?

Comment: does anyone know fix?

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT  okay, may i know what about this one:   <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />   , will this work? if yes, which one is preferred and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to place the web.config file at the root of the application folder.And after making changes try to restart the application.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753669/azure-app-service-not-working-with-custom-routing-in-react-redux-web-app-need/50767709) for matching pattern .
Also check to allow wide range of urls by allowing CORS in any of the ways mentioned in references here

1. [spring-boot-security-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors?msclkid=8586e017ba3e11ec89c14ed9ad05f06f)
2. [how-to-enable-spring-boot-cors-example-crossorigin](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring-boot/how-to-enable-spring-boot-cors-example-crossorigin.html#:%7E:text=Spring%20enables%20CORS%20by%20providing%20the%20%40CrossOrigin%20annotation.,Let%E2%80%99s%20permit%20our%20%2Fgreet%20method%20from%20cross-origin%20requests.?msclkid=858539feba3e11ec893177756fed1684)
3. [/spring-boot-security-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286549/spring-boot-security-cors?msclkid=9204a671ba3f11ec9394dc5b2a7ff770)

ex:

```
         registry.addMapping("/*")
          .allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*");
```

And as a workaround try to add
 `<system.webServer>     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>   </system.webServer>`
in web.config