# React Router works on Localhost but not on Live server(Azure)

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core

I published .Net core & react webb app on azure. The links were working fine on local server but once i ran npm run build and buplished the contents of build folder to live server then everything works fine but links not working and gives 404 error.
in App.js :

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';

import './App.css';
import PRODUCTS from './Components/Products';
import CUSTOMERS from './Components/Customers';
import STORES from './Components/Store';
import SALES from './Components/Sales';
import NavigationBar from './Components/Navbar';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router> 
            <NavigationBar />  
            <div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<CUSTOMERS />}>         </Route>
                    <Route path="/customers" element={<CUSTOMERS />}>         </Route>
                    <Route path="/products" element={<PRODUCTS/>} >   </Route>
                    <Route path="/stores" element={<STORES/>} >   </Route>
                    <Route path="/sales" element={<SALES/>} >   </Route>
                 </Routes>             
            </div> 
        </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

in navbar.js

```
   import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

const NavigationBar = () => {
    return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#">Onboarding App</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="/customers">Customers</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/products">Products</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/stores">Stores</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/sales">Sales</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

export default NavigationBar;
```

[image]

https://onbo2023-frontend.azurewebsites.net/products

Comment: refer to this for [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1331049/enable-url-routing-in-an-app-service-however-each?page=1)[2](https://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/)

Comment: could you try setting the link to like this "<NavLink to="/route">". also set the react routing rule in your app

Comment: add a `web.config` ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration> <system.webServer>  <rewrite> <rules><rule name="React Routes"stopProcessing="true"> <match url=".*" /> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /></conditions><action type="Rewrite" url="/" /></rule> </rules></rewrite></system.webServer></configuration>```

Answer (score 0):

you need to work on your `web.config` settings
here is a similar issue

[Azure App service not working with custom routing in React-Redux web app - need wildcard virtual directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753669/azure-app-service-not-working-with-custom-routing-in-react-redux-web-app-need)